# Check_mk time periods

Tags: nagios, system-monitoring, check-mk

I have a Check_MK **Raw 1.4.0p21** setup on a Ubuntu box **16.04.3 LTS**.

I`m having difficultie getting Check_MK to respect WATO Time periode.
As you can see in the code block, i have a window between 04:56 and 06:59 where servers are rebooted and upgrading. Therefor i do not want any notifications about hosts are down and services not responding. Basically suppress all emailing and notifications in this time period.

My time periode "Rebooting" is attached to my notification rule. The rule is connected in the way that the checkbox "Match only during timeperiode" is matched.

```
Monday          [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
Tuesday         [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
Wednesday       [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
Thursday        [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
Friday          [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
Saturday        [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
Sunday          [07:00] -  [24:00] [00:01] - [04:55]
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

All help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If anyone else struggles with the same issue, i resolved it by doing the following

Select your host -> parameters -> Service period for hosts and make a rule, then select your time period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method one - Schedule downtime for the particular host-group by executing commands on the hosts, service and other objects, choose custom time range and schedule downtime.

The second method - WATO Configuration-> Time Periods à define time period
WATO Configuration->Notifications -> created new rule

Notification Method -> cancel previous notification,

Match host -> selected host group

Match only during time period --> Selected rule which you have created under “Time Periods”